# How do I include a javascript file into my nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to add a snippet of Javascript code to a reverse-proxied site via nginx.

In particular, I have a sub_filter rule that works like so:

```
sub_filter </head>
  '</head><script language="javascript">
     console.log("hello world")
   </script>';
```

Is there a way for me to refactor this script to it's own file and load it from there. Something like:

```
sub_filter </head>
  '</head>$load_script_from('/src/tracking')';
```

Or is this impossible, and should I use `gulp` to compile my `nginx.conf` from a bunch of other files?

Here is my complete `nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {

            sub_filter </head>
            '</head><script>console.log("hello world")</script>';

            proxy_pass 10.1.1.1:80;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using [Openresty](https://openresty.org/en/), which lets you use nginx in lua. I saved an injection script, and loaded the file into a variable using `set_by_lua_block`.

```
set_by_lua_block $injection_script {
  local f = io.open("/path/to/file.js", "rb")
  local content = f:read("*all")
  f:close()
  return content
}

sub_filter '</head>' "<script>${injection_script}</script></head>";
```